# GraphQL resolution using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I'm very much a newbie in the field of JavaScript and NodeJS.  I have a lot of experience in both Java and C# but this is all quite new to me.

As a POC, I'm trying to wrap a salesforce call with GraphQL.  Since the call to salesforce is async, I want to return a promise to GraphQL when I define the bindings between the schema and the underlying query.

When I do this, however, I get the message "Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field Query.getAccounts."

Here's my absolutely awful code:

```
conn.login('username', 'password' + 'security-token', function(err, userInfo) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log("Cannot login to Salesforce");
  } else {
    var root = {
      getAccounts: function ({offset, limit}) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          conn.query("SELECT Id, Name FROM Account", function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
              reject();
            }
            resolve(result);
          });
        });
      }
    }


    var app = express();
    app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
      schema: schema,
      rootValue: root,
      graphiql: true,
    }));
    app.listen(4000);
    console.log('Running a GraphQL API server at localhost:4000/graphql');
  }
});
```

Should I be using Apollo?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that the response from Salesforce wasn't in a list format.  So I had to chain another promise in to pull the actual data I cared about out of the response.

Basically, it's a misleading message from GraphQL.